# How to convert a list to an object with key duplications in OPA Rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I am new to Open Policy Agent (OPA) and Rego language. I need to convert a list of objects which I get from input to an object (in best case in O(n) time). The problem is that used key may be duplicated in a list. Input example:

```
[
    {
        "id": "a",
        "body": {...}
    },
    {
        "id": "b",
        "body": {...}
    },
    {
        "id": "a",
        "body": {...}
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "id": "a",
            "body": {...}
        },
        {
            "id": "a",
            "body": {...}
        }
    ],
    "b": [
        {
            "id": "b",
            "body": {...}
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the best option to do this? I tried to create a function, but output is never evaluated:

```
package test

inpt := [
    {"id": "a", "body":{"a":1}},
    {"id": "b", "body":{"a":1}},
    {"id": "a", "body":{"a":2}},
]

x := f(inpt)

f(input_list) = output_obj {
    output_obj := {}
    inner := input_list[_]
    inner_list = object.get(output_obj, inner.id, [])
    merged := array.concat(inner_list, [inner])
    output_obj[inner.id] = merged
}
```

The only option I found is inner loop (O(n^2)):

```
output_obj := {i.id : [j | j:= inpt[_]; j.id == i.id] | i := inpt[_]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comprehension indexing](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-performance/#comprehension-indexing) should ensure O(n) runtime complexity given the rule meets the conditions for that (which yours does):

```
package test

output_obj := {id: list |
    some i
    id := input[i].id
    list := [obj |
        some j
        input[j].id == id
        obj := input[j]
    ]
}
```